# Android Bluetooth Low Energy - read Service Description

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We're building a Bluetooth LE device, and it's allowing us to specify a Description for our Service.

When I connect to this device from my Android phone, I can't find any way to query the device to retrieve this description field.  I see how to query the description of the characteristic, but not the service.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if perhaps the 'Description' is actually the name really for the device, which obviously has a strong association with the main service that it offers.  The device name can (optionally) be sent in its advertising packet. Then in the Android phone - in the ScanCallBack - in onScanResult - `scanResult.getDevice().getName()` will retrieve this value.